# How to mock a method inside a method using JEST?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to unit test a method called `search` which has three methods such as `buildSearchParameter`, `isUnknownFields`, `readAll`. I need to mock them but I have no idea how to do it. can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplify the question, I remove the static types for it. You can use `jest.spyOn` to make stubs for these three methods. Here is the unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
import ModelUtility from './ModelUtility';

enum EndpointType {
  SEARCH = 'SEARCH',
}

export class SomeClass {
  schemaConstants;
  errorConstants = {
    invalidQueryParameters: 'invalid',
  };

  search = async (query, endpointConstants) => {
    const searchParam = ModelUtility.buildSearchParameter(query, endpointConstants, this.schemaConstants);
    // check for unknown fields
    const isUnknownFields = ModelUtility.isUnknownFields(EndpointType.SEARCH, searchParam, this.schemaConstants);
    if (isUnknownFields) {
      return this.errorConstants.invalidQueryParameters;
    }
    return this.readAll(query, searchParam, endpointConstants);
  };

  readAll(...args) {
    return 'real data';
  }
}
```

`ModelUtility.ts`:

```js
export default {
  buildSearchParameter(...args) {
    return 'real search parameter';
  },
  isUnknownFields(...args) {
    return true;
  },
};
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { SomeClass } from './';
import ModelUtility from './ModelUtility';

describe('SomeClass', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('should return invalid query parameters', async () => {
    const buildSearchParameterSpy = jest
      .spyOn(ModelUtility, 'buildSearchParameter')
      .mockReturnValueOnce('mocked search parameter');
    const isUnknownFieldsSpy = jest.spyOn(ModelUtility, 'isUnknownFields').mockReturnValueOnce(true);

    const instance = new SomeClass();
    const actual = await instance.search('mocked query', 'endpointConstants');
    expect(actual).toBe('invalid');
    expect(buildSearchParameterSpy).toBeCalledWith('mocked query', 'endpointConstants', undefined);
    expect(isUnknownFieldsSpy).toBeCalledWith('SEARCH', 'mocked search parameter', undefined);
  });

  it('should return correctly', async () => {
    const buildSearchParameterSpy = jest
      .spyOn(ModelUtility, 'buildSearchParameter')
      .mockReturnValueOnce('mocked search parameter');
    const isUnknownFieldsSpy = jest.spyOn(ModelUtility, 'isUnknownFields').mockReturnValueOnce(false);

    const instance = new SomeClass();
    jest.spyOn(instance, 'readAll').mockReturnValueOnce('mocked data');
    const actual = await instance.search('mocked query', 'endpointConstants');
    expect(actual).toBe('mocked data');
    expect(buildSearchParameterSpy).toBeCalledWith('mocked query', 'endpointConstants', undefined);
    expect(isUnknownFieldsSpy).toBeCalledWith('SEARCH', 'mocked search parameter', undefined);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59207566/index.spec.ts
  SomeClass
    ✓ should return invalid query parameters (7ms)
    ✓ should return correctly (1ms)

-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File             |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files        |    72.73 |      100 |    57.14 |    73.68 |                   |
 ModelUtility.ts |       20 |      100 |        0 |       20 |           2,3,5,6 |
 index.ts        |    88.24 |      100 |       80 |    92.86 |                24 |
-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.891s, estimated 11s
```